# Reduce size to 1/10 to 1/4 w/o audio?

Tags: ffmpeg

I've used OBS the best that I could, which mean not that good, to make a medium-sized 720p video w/o audio, well I managed to make a large-sized 720p video w/ audio, here's its info

```
General
Unique ID                                : 229628658475078735632868317480151920466 (0xACC0DEF63AB99E4D733E5C1F3EF7AF52)
Complete name                            : C:\Users\CENSORED\Videos\2021-01-25 17-03-43.mkv
Format                                   : Matroska
Format version                           : Version 4
File size                                : 411 MiB
Duration                                 : 1 min 5 s
Overall bit rate                         : 53.0 Mb/s
Writing application                      : Lavf58.29.100
Writing library                          : Lavf58.29.100
ErrorDetectionType                       : Per level 1

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L3.1
Format settings                          : CABAC / 4 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, Reference frames        : 4 frames
Format settings, GOP                     : M=1, N=30
Codec ID                                 : V_MPEG4/ISO/AVC
Duration                                 : 1 min 5 s
Width                                    : 1 280 pixels
Height                                   : 720 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 30.000 FPS
Standard                                 : Component
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Default                                  : Yes
Forced                                   : No
Color range                              : Limited
Color primaries                          : BT.709
Transfer characteristics                 : BT.709
Matrix coefficients                      : BT.709

Audio
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AAC LC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec Low Complexity
Codec ID                                 : A_AAC-2
Duration                                 : 1 min 5 s
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel layout                           : L R
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
Frame rate                               : 46.875 FPS (1024 SPF)
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Title                                    : simple_aac_recording
Default                                  : Yes
Forced                                   : No
```

Is there a way to get down to something with a more reasonable size, say to 1/10 to 1/4 of what it is? I'd also like to keep the file as it is in the process (so the desired-result will be in another file).

Thank you kindly

**Update 1**

As one can see from a 63 seconds video, compared to my 65 secs one, in

```
[info] Available formats for 5rYIDyBxn88:
format code  extension  resolution note
249          webm       audio only tiny   51k , opus @ 50k (48000Hz), 380.78KiB
250          webm       audio only tiny   67k , opus @ 70k (48000Hz), 499.84KiB
140          m4a        audio only tiny  130k , m4a_dash container, mp4a.40.2@128k (44100Hz), 985.71KiB
251          webm       audio only tiny  131k , opus @160k (48000Hz), 985.77KiB
278          webm       192x144    144p   63k , webm container, vp9, 30fps, video only, 455.19KiB
160          mp4        192x144    144p   64k , avc1.4d400c, 30fps, video only, 325.20KiB
242          webm       320x240    240p  128k , vp9, 30fps, video only, 837.98KiB
133          mp4        320x240    240p  146k , avc1.4d400d, 30fps, video only, 716.53KiB
243          webm       480x360    360p  285k , vp9, 30fps, video only, 1.70MiB
134          mp4        480x360    360p  291k , avc1.4d401e, 30fps, video only, 1.38MiB
135          mp4        640x480    480p  419k , avc1.4d401e, 30fps, video only, 2.29MiB
244          webm       640x480    480p  533k , vp9, 30fps, video only, 2.85MiB
136          mp4        960x720    720p  815k , avc1.4d401f, 30fps, video only, 4.32MiB
247          webm       960x720    720p 1085k , vp9, 30fps, video only, 5.82MiB
248          webm       1440x1080  1080p 1900k , vp9, 30fps, video only, 11.88MiB
137          mp4        1440x1080  1080p 3071k , avc1.640028, 30fps, video only, 12.52MiB
271          webm       1920x1440  1440p 6334k , vp9, 30fps, video only, 38.79MiB
18           mp4        480x360    360p  621k , avc1.42001E, 30fps, mp4a.40.2@ 96k (44100Hz), 4.61MiB
22           mp4        960x720    720p 2144k , avc1.64001F, 30fps, mp4a.40.2@192k (44100Hz) (best)
```

for entries 136 & 247, with the larger being 5.82MiB, it seems that 1/10 should be *easily* within my reach.

**Update 2**

I managed to do it using MediaCoder, but since I intend to do it multiple times and I'd like for it to be applied uniformly, I'd love to me able to do it by CLI; I'm on Windows, so command prompt.

I thought to myself 10 Mb was a good size for 65 secs and that amounted to ~17 Kbps, so I chose the closest in the GUI: 15000. I then chose 3 pass, then had for container MP4, lastly in audio tab disabled it (1st check-mark). Although even though I had the bitrate lower than I calculated, it ended up being larger than I intended for it, weird!

Comment: A more accurate answer can be given if you show info about the original input.

Comment: Don't you see a blockquote right after "I managed to make a large-sized 720p video w/ audio, here's its info" ? That is what you're referring to.

Comment: Yes, i saw the quote. But yy "its" I assumed you meant the output video you created, not the input that you used to create this output. I don't need info about the video you created, but I need info about the original source video.

Comment: What are you talking about? The quote mention it's a 400 Mb video and I mention its large! That's the original video. Don't you see in Update 2 that what I managed to do with the GUI was an audioless MP4 just over 10 Mb? You asked for the original input then I write you "That is what you're referring to." Do I have to clarify every last bit of things on this site? Or is it only for you? Also the 1st blockquote mention it's of Matroska format and has for extention .mkv and it includes audio.